# How can I make the resizers draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

If you look at this demo the resizers are draggable: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html

```
<head>
    <title>Summation</title>
    <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="rotaercz.layout.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').layout({ 
                applyDefaultStyles: true
            });

            $('#inner').layout({
                applyDefaultStyles: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui-layout-north">North</div>
    <div class="ui-layout-center" id="inner">
        <div class="ui-layout-center">Inner Center</div>
        <div class="ui-layout-south">Inner South</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-layout-west">West</div>
</body>
```

This is what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/JPEaa/1/

How can I make the resizers draggable like in the demo? I can't seem to figure it out. It's draggable in jsfiddle but doesn't seem to work in Google Chrome.

A secondary question I have is how can I make the margins for Inner Center and Inner South 0? I tried margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You forget to include jQuery UI in your fiddle. Check [this box](http://i.stack.imgur.com/agzbi.png).

Comment: Thanks, updated. Any idea how to make the resizer draggable?

Comment: @rotaercz why you want to make the margins for Inner Center and Inner South to zero?

Comment: Because there's a bit of wasted space between the Inner area and the outer center area. Do you know what I need to change for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I just didn't have the following line...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
```